# NuGet can't find/download packages after upgrade to 3.4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I just updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update **2** from Update **1**, and I also updated to NuGet 3.4. ([The Update 2 release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#nuget) suggest this NuGet version corresponds to this Visual Studio update.)

After doing this, Visual Studio package restore is broken. When I try to download any NuGet package, I get an error like this:

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '2.10.11' of package 'NPoco'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem occurred by me after the NuGet 3.4 update last week.
Solution is to delete your 'NuGet.Config' file in '%AppData%\NuGet\', when you start VS2015 again it will create a new default config file.

[image: NuGet settings with v3]

Detailed instructions at:
https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/Known-Issues

Working config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks; I just tested this and it seems to work fine. The resulting NuGet config seems the same as the one produced by my answer, but I've accepted this one since it looks like the official answer.

Comment: No problem. I have now also added a screenshot of the end result, did not have enough rep before this post to add one.

Comment: When I deleted my `NuGet.Config` file, my NuGet config dialog looked the same as yours except without anything present under *Available package sources* and with the item under *Machine-wide packages* ticked. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and NuGet 3.4.1.807, and I'm not running Visual Studio as an admin.

Comment: My 'Available package sources' was empty as well after updating but was restored after following the above steps. Did you close VS2015 as well before deleting the file?
My NuGet version is the same as yours, however my VS2015 is still at update 1.
I'll update my answer with my current config file.

Comment: Yeah, I had Visual Studio closed when I did this as well. I'm not sure why my config ended up different to yours, but the main thing is it works, so not a big deal. :)

Comment: This worked for me. I was upgrading from 2015 to 2017.

Answer (score 2):

When I went into the NuGet settings, the package sources were unticked. Ticking the package source fixed the problem. I guess either the VS 2015 Update 2 installation or the NuGet 3.4 installation caused this to become unticked.

[image: Ticketing the "Microsoft and .NET" package source under Settings -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources]

Comment: That does not fix the problem

Comment: @Toddams, it fixed it for me, so maybe something else is causing the problem on your end. I just double-checked, and for me, this is definitely what makes the difference between getting the error in the question and everything working correctly.

Comment: I concur, it fixed it for me too.  Thanks @Sam for your post!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the curated-feeds don't have that package. Try adding the uncurated-feed (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2).

Comment: This was my problem, the above url must show in the "Available Package sources" box.

Comment: The error was occurring for *all* NuGet packages for me, so I don't think this was the problem. (I just updated the question to add emphasis.)

Answer (score 1):

For me - I had to uncheck "show prereleases" - then my search returned to normal.